# Adding row in R with next day and 0 in each column

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with 4 columns. The first column is `the_day`, from 11/1/15 until 11/30/15. The next 3 have values corresponding to each day based on `amount_raised`. However, some dates are missing because there were no values in the next 3 columns (no money was raised).

For example, 11/3/15 is missing. What I want to do is add a row in between 11/2/15 and 11/4/15 with the date, and zeros in the next 3 columns. So it would read like this:

```
11/3/2015   0    0    0
```

Do I have to create a vector and then add it into the existing `data.frame`? I feel like there has to be a quicker way.

Comment: Please `dput` your data set.

Comment: And  the expected output

Comment: structure(list(the_day = structure(c(16742, 16743, 16744, 16745, 
16746, 16747), class = "Date"), inf = c("1.32", "4.25", "3.25", 
"1", "4.75", "32"), specified = c("156", "40", "25", "15", "10", 
"0"), both = c("157.32", "44.25", "28.25", "16", "14.75", "32"
)), .Names = c("the_day", "inf", "specified", "both"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work,

```
date_seq <- seq(min(df$the_day),max(df$the_day),by = 1)
rbind(df,cbind(the_day = as.character( date_seq[!date_seq %in% df$the_day]), inf = "0", specified = "0", both = "0"))

#   the_day  inf specified   both
# 1 2015-11-02 1.32       156 157.32  
# 2 2015-11-04 4.25        40  44.25
# 3 2015-11-05 3.25        25  28.25
# 4 2015-11-06    1        15     16
# 5 2015-11-07 4.75        10  14.75
# 6 2015-11-08   32         0     32
# 7 2015-11-03    0         0      0
```

If you want sort it according to `the_day`, take the data frame in a variable and use the `order` function

```
ans <- rbind(df,cbind(the_day = as.character( date_seq[!date_seq %in% df$the_day]), inf = "0", specified = "0", both = "0"))
ans[order(ans$the_day), ]

#   the_day  inf specified   both
# 1 2015-11-02 1.32       156 157.32 
# 7 2015-11-03    0         0      0
# 2 2015-11-04 4.25        40  44.25
# 3 2015-11-05 3.25        25  28.25
# 4 2015-11-06    1        15     16
# 5 2015-11-07 4.75        10  14.75
# 6 2015-11-08   32         0     32
```

Answer (score 0):

data.frames are not efficient to work with row-wise internally.  I would suggest something along the following lines:

1. create empty (zero) 30x3 matrix.  This will include your amount_raised.
2. create a complete sequence of dates from 11/1 till 11/30
3. for each existing date, find it's match in the complete sequence
4. copy the corresponding line from your data frame to the matched line in the matrix (use match() function).
5. Eventually, make a new data frame out of the new sequence and matrix.